# Access ARKit functionality from a PWA in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, progressive-web-apps

As of today (Nov 2023) it is not possible to use ARKit functionality in a progressive web app. My thinking is that it might be possible to create a "backend" api that a user interface may interact with by way of a web app container written in swift.

inspiration: https://www.vsanthanam.com/writing/2018/5/9/web-app-containers-in-ios

has anyone attempted this, or had similar ideas?

IOS does not support accessing the ARKit API from PWA's.